# Apache httpClient retrying POST request while ignoring timeouts

Tags: java, apache, post, aem

I'm currently trying to build an OSGi service that sends a POST request to a defined API.  This API is used to virus-scan a file which is contained in the request body (JSON) as Base64 string. 
For this, I am using Apache HttpClient contained in Adobe AEM uberjar v6.4.0

My current implementation works fine for smaller files (<2 MB), but as filesize gets bigger, the behaviour gets strange:
**When I upload a 9 MB file, the request executes for ~1 minute, then gets a HTTP400 as response and afterwards retrys the request 7 times.**

I tried to use a timeout with the request. If the timeout is below 60.000ms, a TimeoutException is thrown, if it's greater than 60.000ms, I get a HTTP400 Bad Request. I guess the latter is the APIs fault which I need to clarify.

However, in both cases after the exception is thrown, httpClient retries the request and I have not been able to prevent that since. I'm struggeling with many deprecated "HowTo's" on the web and now I'm here.

I have shortened the code a bit, as it's somehow big (mostly removing debug messages and some "if... return false" at the beginning). My Code:

```
public boolean isAttachmentClean(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, JSONException, ServiceUnavailableException {

    //prevent httpClient from retrying in case of an IOException
    final HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, false);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setRetryHandler(retryHandler).build();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serviceUrl);

    httpPost.setHeader("accept", "application/json");
    //set some more headers...

    //set timeout for POST from OSGi Config
    RequestConfig timeoutConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(serviceTimeout)
            .setConnectTimeout(serviceTimeout)
            .setSocketTimeout(serviceTimeout)
            .build();
    httpPost.setConfig(timeoutConfig);

    //create request body data
    String requestBody;
    try {
        requestBody = buildDataJson(inputStream);
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
    HttpEntity requestBodyEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(requestBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    httpPost.setEntity(requestBodyEntity);

    //Execute and get the response.
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpServletResponse.SC_OK){
        httpPost.abort();
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException("API not available, Response Code was "+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    boolean result = false;
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream apiResult = entity.getContent();
        try {

            // check the response from the API (Virus yes or no)
            result = evaluateResponse(apiResult);
        } finally {
            apiResult.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

"buildDataJson()" simply reads the InputStream and creates a JSON needed for the API call.
"evaluateResponse()" also reads the InputStream, transforms it into a JSON and checks for a property named "Status:" "Clean".

I'd appreciate any tipps on why this request is retried over and over again.

*/edit: So far, I found that Apache httpClient has some default mechanism that retries a request in case of an IOException - which is what I get here. Still, I have not found a solution on how to deactivate these retries.*

Comment: Can you please give us more information about the "Virus Scan API"? In general encoding files as Base64 string and sending them as JSON payload does not sound like a good idea. You are bound to get in trouble. If you have an asset with 2GB size you will have a hard time encoding that as Base64. Maybe the API allows to send files as part of a `multipart/form-data` POST request? Those are made to send "big" files (within reason).

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it states simply "application/json". I'd have to clarify that with the API development.
However, we do not intend to send big data over that API. The desired limit is around 10MB, but we are currently having problems with files >5 MB. I know that Base64 encoding will impair the request speed, but I seem to have no other choice.

Do you think the duration of the encodig process relates to the issue of the httpClient retrying the POST request?

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say your requests are send multiple times because `HttpClient` tries to re-send failed requests. Search for `HttpRequestRetryHandler` to get more information.

Comment: Hi, my fault, I shoud have included this. As far as I understood, httpClient has a default mechanism that **retries all failed requests in case of any IOException** - which is the case here. So far, I wasn't able to deactivate this behaviour.